# Arduino—global variables losing their value

Tags: arduino

I have two variables, `alarmMinute` and `alarmHour`

I have them printing out every loop, and if I have this code, then `alarmMinute` falls to 0 after the first loop.

```
if(buttonPushed){
  alarmMinute += 5;
  if(alarmMinute > 60){
    alarmMinute = 0;
  }
}
```

Monitor output:

```
alarmHour: 14    alarmMinute: 28    currentSeconds: 6913    alarmSeconds: 6720    timeGap: 193    alarmLength: 300    AlarmProgress: 64
alarmHour: 14    alarmMinute: 0    currentSeconds: 6913    alarmSeconds: 5040    timeGap: 1873    alarmLength: 300    AlarmProgress: 0
alarmHour: 14    alarmMinute: 0    currentSeconds: 6914    alarmSeconds: 5040    timeGap: 1874    alarmLength: 300    AlarmProgress: 0
```

BUT if I comment out that code:

```
if(buttonPushed){
// alarmMinute += 5;
// if(alarmMinute > 60){
//   alarmMinute = 0;
// }
}
```

Then I lose the value of `alarmHour` instead:

```
alarmHour: 14    alarmMinute: 28    currentSeconds: 7052    alarmSeconds: 6720    timeGap: 332    alarmLength: 300    AlarmProgress: 0
alarmHour: 0    alarmMinute: 28    currentSeconds: 7052    alarmSeconds: 1680    timeGap: 5372    alarmLength: 300    AlarmProgress: 0
alarmHour: 0    alarmMinute: 28    currentSeconds: 7053    alarmSeconds: 1680    timeGap: 5373    alarmLength: 300    AlarmProgress: 0
```

---

In both cases, I'm *not* pushing the button, so the code shouldn't be running at all. Also, when it has the value of `28` the code shouldn't affect `alarmMinute`, and commenting out that code *definitely* shouldn't affect the value of `alarmHour`, does anyone have an idea of what's happening? Have I run out of memory or something?

Comment: Maybe the problem lies in the code you didn't show. Please post a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: Do you change your global variables insided interrupt routines? If yes, have you declared the variables as volatile?

Comment: @Guille It's somewhat complicated to post a minimal example, but I can promise you that no other part of the code ever assigns any value to `alarmMinute` apart from the initial declaration `int alarmMinute = 28`.

Comment: @Fitzi there are no volatile variables nor interrupt routines in the program

Comment: As it is complicated to post a minimal example, it's even more complicated to guess what's wrong with the non-posted code.

Comment: Are you sure your connection is OK? I mean first, check the button wire connection and remember that it is better to use a pull-up resistor on your switch. Then try to write a minimal code to print button state and then proceed with your current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the problem—I had a `char[12]` array but accidentally padded it out with 13 leading spaces.

The reason why changing seemingly random parts of the code caused different variables to disappear is that whatever was in memory next to the array gets wiped.

This is the basic principle of the heartbleed cyber attack—referencing an array beyond its bounds.